# Blinking cursor after debian 9 to 10 dist-upgrade

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, gdm

So as the title says, I updated to debian 10.
I modified /etc/apt/source.list and replaced every instance of stretch to buster
Then i did

```
# apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade
```

after the reboot, i was booting in TTY
I tried to restart gdm, but every time I get a white blinking cursor
Same with lxdm or sddm or lightdm I tried them all haha

I tried to reinstall/purge gnome, gdm, xorg, xorg-server-core and nvidia drivers, same outcome ...
I don't know what my next step would be at the moment

I'll be more than happy to provide logs or command outputs if needed

Thanks in advance,
Kcinnad

Comment: Looking through logs is probably your best bet: somebody is failing so there should be an entry somewhere - `/var/log/messages`, the X log, the journal... Somebody with Debian experience should be able to tell you where to look exactly: I just don't know enough about debian to help more, but I would start by looking at all the files in /var/log and seeing what's the most recently modified.

Comment: Why wouldn't reinstall the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was my problem
The nvidia driver did not installed itself when I dist-upgraded because the new kernel-headers package in the buster repo was not installed(it was missing dependencies) I ended up changing my repos to the testing branch in order to get it to work again

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

Make sure all of the things you purged that were installed when the system worked are installed and not broken and make sure they are configured. apt-get fix-missing, apt-get fix-broken, and once all complete without error. Make sure all is up to date, update, upgrade, dist-upgrade...

Then:

```
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

> Note if dconf is not installed install it...

If that does not work, try installing a different desktop enviroment.

```
apt-get install lxde
make sure to set it as default during install.
```